# Computing HASH160 of a Taproot X-only 32 byte Public Key

Tags: public-key, hash, taproot, p2tr, x-only-pubkeys

I know that Taproot does not use pubkey hashes, but I want to compute a HASH160 of a 32 byte Taproot X-only public key anyway. The rationale is to compare it to an existing 20 byte HASH160 from a Witness V0 ScriptPubKey, to see if the same underlying public key is used in both outputs.

Is it correct to just pre-pend 0x02 byte to the 32-byte `XOnlyPublicKey`?
I sketched this using rust-bitcoin:

```rust
// Taproot. In the case of the key-path spend, the pub key is not tweaked.
//It is 32-byte only X-coordinate however, missing the 33-d byte Y "tie-breaker"
//https://archive.is/AsKEb
//From BIP 340: "To avoid gratuitous incompatibilities, we pick that option for P, and thus
//our X-only public keys become equivalent to a compressed public key that is the X-only key prefixed by the byte 0x02."
let witness_program_bytes = program.program().as_bytes();
//Y-coordinate absent:
assert_eq!(witness_program_bytes.len(), 32);
let mut witness_program_vec = witness_program_bytes.to_vec();
//BIP 340:
witness_program_vec.insert(0, 0x02);
// it is the actual compressed 33 byte pubkey
let pk = PublicKey::from_slice(&witness_program_vec).unwrap();
```